# Adding SSL certificates to Docker linux container

Tags: docker, ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

**Expected behavior**
Being able to make HTTPs calls from within the container

**Actual behavior**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://identity.test/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://identity.test/.we
ll-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.CurlException: SSL connect error
```

**Information**
I think the problem is that my container doesn't know at all about the certificates that need to be used for this http call. So what I tried to do is providing them to the container itself through the dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

#Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY PublishOutput/. ./

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app .

COPY Certificates/myCertificate.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myCertificate
RUN update-ca-certificates

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CaseApi.Web.dll"]
```

Inside the **PublishOutput** folder I just have all the dlls of my .net core api that I need to run inside the Docker container.

When I build the dockerfile it says:

```
Step 8/9 : RUN update-ca-certificates
 ---> Running in b025a42f2edc
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

which makes me think that the certificate I want to use isn't being really used. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was u ever able to solve the issue? Have exactly the same problem and performed exactly the same steps that u did

Comment: @managerger are you sure the extension is .crt and that if you open them with nodepad++ you see a -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- block?

Comment: Yes, sir. Absolutely

Comment: @managerger okey! also sure that you copy them in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ ? The **update-ca-certificates** command reads the certificates from that folder: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html  . Let me know if this helps

Comment: @managerger Also, does it say **0 added, 0 removed; done.** for you?

Comment: After I copied CA to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and now it says **1 added, 0 removed; done**. But, unfortunately, I still can't reach `'https://localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration'` due to error `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`.
But when I curl witj parameter `-k` everything works fine. So it seems that the issue is with CA itself. Do u have any ideas what it could be?

Comment: @managerger added an answer down below, check it out and let me know!

Comment: No luck here, still the same

Comment: @managerger then you are not passing the right certificates.. it's not anymore about how to pass the certificates because the **1 added, 0 removed** it's che confirmation that the system is reading them correctly. Tell me a bit more of your setup.. where is the IdentityServer hosted? can you access its bindings? are you able to see which certificate it wants?

Comment: I did some more research and found out that it dosen't really matter what kind of app runs in container. 

Anyway, if one app from docker container tries to connect another app in docker container over `https` the issue appears. If I send request from outside of container, everything is okay.

Comment: @managerger but so your identityserver is within a docker container?

Comment: Yes, sir. Whole issue is about communication problem over `https` between docker containers when certificate is self signed (untrusted)

Comment: oh... then it's another pair of sleeves.. I think the situation is the same but honestly my IdentityServer is not in a docker container.. I am sorry :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to follow:

1) Make sure the extension of the certificates is .crt

2) Open the certificates to Notepad++ or similar

3) Copy the certificates into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ . The **update-ca-certificates** command reads the certificates from that folder: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html

4) After these steps building the dockerfile should result in NOT saying anymore **0 added, 0 removed;** but **1 added, 0 removed;** or similar, depending on how many certificates you added

5) solution may not be there yet. Certificates depend on a hierarchy of other certificates. I am in windows and by going to the Certificate Manager I can see that my certificate depends on 2 higher ones (this is shown in the Certification Path):

[image: Certification Path]

Thus, you need to be sure to put into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ ALL the certificates in the hierarchy.

6) Still, you might be thinking to pass the right certificates but maybe you are not. In my case IdentityServer was hosted on IIS, in the bindings I could see that IdentityServer was indeed expecting calls through https and by double-clicking on the binding I could see the certificate that IdentityServer requires for accepting the call.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is in `update-ca-certificates`. The command only process files with the extension `.crt`. From its man page:

> Certificates must have a .crt extension in order to be included by
>   update-ca-certificates.

So just add this extension when copying the certificate in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY Certificates/myCertificate.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/myCertificate.crt
```

Comment: tried that as well.. by just changing the extension on the host itself directly yo .crt .. but unfortunately the problem is still the same

Answer (score 0):

If you created your certificate correctly, it should automatically have the *.crt extension. Revisit how you created your certificate. Be sure that the certificate domain info is the same as your actual domain name.